# How to get 'proof' like this?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, macros, environments

I'm using the following codes

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
     %------------------------------------------------------------
      \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}           
        %------------------------------------------------------------
         \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
         \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    % ------------------------------------------------------------
    \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
     \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
     \newtheorem{definitions}{Definitions}[section]
     \newtheorem{notation}{Notation}[section]
    \newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
   \newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
  \newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
  \newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
  \newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
  \numberwithin{equation}{section}
    \begin{document}
    \section{section1}
    \begin{theorem}
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{proof}
    \end{proof}
     \end{document}
```

I hope to get the proof like this

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: `\begin{proof}...\end{proof}` and redefinition of `\qedsymbol` since you're using `amsthm` already

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand very well what do you mean

Comment: Read the `amsthm` documentation, it's described in there

Comment: When I write `        \begin{proof}
        \qedsymbol
        \end{proof}` , there is no change.

Comment: I did not write that you should use `\qedsymbol` inside the `proof` environment, I wrote **redefinition** of `\qedsymbol`

Comment: Could you please write me the codes because I'm beguinner and thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `proof` environment and redefine `\qedsymbol` to, say, `$\blacksquare$`, which is an `amsmath/amssymb` symbol. `\qedsymbol` is automatically appended at the end of the `proof` environment typesetting.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
% ------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}           
% ------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% ------------------------------------------------------------
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{definitions}{Definitions}[section]
\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}
\let\origproofname\proofname
\renewcommand{\proofname}{\upshape\textbf{\origproofname}}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\begin{document}
\section{section1}
\begin{proof}
  Foo
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

In order to cope with the optional argument, I suggest to use a modified version of the `proof` environment, renaming it to, say, `otherproof` and adding the  changes for font etc. inside the definition.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
% ------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}           
% ------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% ------------------------------------------------------------
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{definitions}{Definitions}[section]
\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]


\makeatletter
\newenvironment{otherproof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
    \textbf{#1}\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

\numberwithin{equation}{section}



\begin{document}
\section{section1}
\begin{otherproof}
  Foo
\end{otherproof}


\begin{otherproof}[Stuff]
  Foobar
\end{otherproof}

\begin{proof}
  Foobar again
\end{proof}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want also the word proof  in bold character

Comment: @Student: Sigh... see the update please

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: In this case `\begin{proof}[foo]` doesn't work well.

Comment: @tomacs: Yes, but that's not the question. The O.P. does not indicate he would use an optional argument at all ;-)